# How to navigate between controllers, swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating analog of iphone's notes in order to studying. I want to make navigation between controllers. And there are two ways: navigation controller and present/dismiss methods. Now I use second.

I have three screens: "list of notes", "watch-note" screen and "edit/make-note" screen. When I go to "existingNote -> edit existingNote" (happening "present" from "list of note" and then "present" from "watch-note" screen), edit it and save, executing dismiss(one time) and my screen became "watch-note screen", it's ok. But when I make note (it happening from the "list of notes" screen) and save, executing dismiss and my screen became "list of notes" screen, but I want to see "watch-note" screen, wanna watch just made note.

Can I do it by present/dismiss or I have to use NavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using present/dismiss:**

You will need to present the "watch-note" screen on "list of notes" silently after make note. This involves two steps:

1. "list of notes" screen should know that "make note" is being dismissed. You can either pass variables between two controllers or use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`
2. When you know the above, present "watch-note" from "list of notes". Remember to use `animated: false` otherwise user will see screen coming up animation.

**Using Navigation Controller: (Highly recommended)**

1. Navigation controller will provide you more flexibility and ability to move between controllers. You can use `navigationController.popToViewController` to pop to desired controller list/watch/make/add notes.
2. Your code won't be messy and will be easy to maintain. You need not pass variables or remember which screen you came from. You can use `navigationController.viewControllers` to know which controllers are in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to identify that you have pushed through navigation controller or presented from view controller i.e., `isBeingPresented`

isBeingPresented is true when the view controller is being presented and false when being pushed.

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

if ([self isBeingPresented]) {
    // being presented
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
} else if ([self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

}